# How to create multi-color border with CSS?

Tags: css, border, css-shapes

How to create multi-color border  like image below?

[image]

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yH59y/

Comment: you can use a border image: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp

Comment: try this: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-gradient-border/

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can do it with `:after` or `:before` psuedo element and css `linear-gradient` as shown below:

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
}

.box {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
}

.box:after {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #bcbcbc 25%,#ffcd02 25%, #ffcd02 50%, #e84f47 50%, #e84f47 75%, #65c1ac 75%);
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 4px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">Div</div>
```

Answer (score 75):

You can do it without `pseudo-elements`, just with `border-image:  linear-gradient`

```css
.fancy-border {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  text-align:center;
  border-top: 5px solid;
  border-image:   linear-gradient(to right, grey 25%, yellow 25%, yellow 50%,red 50%, red 75%, teal 75%) 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="fancy-border">
  my content
</div>
```

Comment: This should be the top answer, it's way less hacky than the currently accepted one.

Comment: How to do it with just 3 colors?

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian just edit the percentages to match. If you only want 3 colors, then divide "100%/3" wich will be 33,33%. Insted of 25% then specify "33%" and so on and you will have only three colors.

Comment: What does/mean the `5` in the end of the `border-image` line?

Comment: @vik I think it's the slice parameter, https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image-slice.asp

Comment: why did you add yellow and red 2 times in the styles

Answer (score 1):

Try it.

```css
.test {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  position: relative;
}

.test:before,
.test:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 10px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, red 20px, blue 20px, blue 40px, yellow 40px, yellow 60px, green 60px, green 80px);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(0deg, red 20px, blue 20px, blue 40px, yellow 40px, yellow 60px, green 60px, green 80px);
  background-size: 80px;
}

.test:before {
  top: 0px;
}

.test:after {
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: It's just the link from the comment?

Comment: for firefox:  

-webkit-border-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#00abeb), to(#fff), color-stop(0.5, #fff), color-stop(0.5, #66cc00)) 21 30 30 21 repeat repeat;