# How to set multi-color border using border-image and linear-gradient?

Tags: css, linear-gradients, border-image

Was trying to make a multi-color bottom border like in below image, but failed.

[image: multi color bottom border]

Tried to use `border-image: linear-gradient()`, but didn't manage. it only gets one of the colors: `#707070`.

[image: only got one color bottom border]

```css
a {
  color: #707070 !important;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 50px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #707070 20%, #a4c0e9 20%, #a4c0e9 80%, #707070 80%) 5;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <a href="/">HOME</a>
  <a href="/projects">PROJECTS</a>
  <a href="/resume">RESUME</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that percentages are relative to the element not the border which will make the `20%` bigger than `5px`.

You need to consider pixel values. You also need to start from the bottom because the top reference is also the top of the element:

```css
a {
  color: #707070 !important;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 50px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid;
  border-image: 
    linear-gradient(to top, #707070 1px, #a4c0e9 1px, #a4c0e9 4px, #707070 4px) 5;
}
```

```html
<a>A link element</a>
```

Or use it as background and it will be easier to handle:

```css
a {
  color: #707070 !important;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 50px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(to bottom, #707070 20%, #a4c0e9 20%, #a4c0e9 80%, #707070 80%) bottom/100% 5px border-box no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<a>A link element</a>
```

Related: [border-image-slice for gradient border image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56914337/8620333)

---

Here is an example to better illustrate the issue you were having:

```css
.box {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  display:inline-block;
  border-bottom:10px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);

}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #707070 20%, #a4c0e9 20%, #a4c0e9 80%, #707070 80%) border-box">
</div>

<div class="box" style="border-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, #707070 20%, #a4c0e9 20%, #a4c0e9 80%, #707070 80%) 10 fill">
</div>

<div class="box" style="border-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, #707070 20%, #a4c0e9 20%, #a4c0e9 80%, #707070 80%) 10 ">
</div>
```

In this example, the first box show the gradient we will be using. In the second one, we are applying it to the border using `fill` to also color the middle area and in the last one we are coloring only the `border-bottom`

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the design you have shown here doesn't look like a gradient. I have a solid color and borders on it. Gradients can be used on border, you can see it [here](https://css-tricks.com/gradient-borders-in-css/)

To achieve what you have shown I would have used :after and following style,

```
 a{
      position: relative;
      padding-bottom: 20px;
    
    &:after{
      position: absolute;
      content: '';
      height: 10px;
      width: 100%;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      background: #a4c0e9;
      border-top: 1px solid #707070;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #707070;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks very much, your way could work. But I think above border-image can also work, considering a similar case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38850419/how-to-create-multi-color-border-with-css

Comment: In these examples, the background colour, in your case #a4c0e9 is coming from a seperate element and they are applying just the gradient on border.