# How could I apply a linear-gradient to an element in css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code:

```css
#trapezoid {
  border-bottom: 150px solid red;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  height: 0;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id='trapezoid'></div>
```

My question is how could I apply linear-gradient to it (the whole shape).

`Background:linear-gradient` will not going to work since I use border to construct the shape.

Any trick I could use?

Thanks

P.S this is not a duplicate of this answer:

[How to create multi-color border with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38850419/how-to-create-multi-color-border-with-css)

Comment: Use an SVG for this.

Comment: @LeeTaylor, I do think about using svg or a combination of transform and perspective to make the shape, but I need to use transform: rotate property afterwards which will not work for me. If you have a way to make trapezoid that could be rotate use svg, I will be very appreicated to see that :)

Comment: You are trying to use gradient borders in CSS. To my knowledge there is no simple obvious CSS API for this. You could do linear-gradient background and try to reproduce the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a trapezoid using CSS clip-path. That way you can set the background-image to a linear-gradient.

```css
.trapezoid {
  width: 20vmin;
  height: 40vmin;
  clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 20% 0, 80% 0, 100% 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, blue);
}
```

```html
<div class="trapezoid"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an SVG trapezoid that has a background linear gradient and also rotates.

```css
@keyframes rotating {
    from{
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to{
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

.shape {
    animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 30 20" class="shape" style="width:300px">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad" x2="0" y2="1">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red"/>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="black"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  
  <polygon points="0, 0, 30, 0, 22, 20, 8, 20" fill="url(#grad)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you, don't know how svg could do that. (very new to it). Thanks again. Really hope I could accept both two answers